# currency issue with jstl + chrome frame

Tags: jsp, google-chrome, browser, cross-browser, google-chrome-frame

I am using JSTL for displaying currency on JSP page as below:

```
<td>${params.currencyCode} < fmt:formatNumber value="${params.verifiedValue}" type="currency" /></td>
```

In IE8 with chrome frame it displays  `¤5,400.12` instead of `$5,400.12`

In other browsers it works fine (i.e. `$5,400.12`)

Any inputs?

Comment: This is impossibly caused by JSP/JSTL as it runs in webserver and procuces HTML; it doesn't run in webbrowser. Pull the webpage in browser (where it works), rightclick and *View Source*. Copypaste exactly that HTML into a plain vanilla `test.html` file in your webapp. Now pull that `test.html` page instead of the JSP page and you'll see that exactly the same problem manifests.

Comment: Thanks for your input. But if webserver rendering html having this issue... it would be same in all browsers.... It works fine in all browsers... breaks only in IE + chrome frame... So i think some browser specific workaround required ...

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm implying :) This is an IE specific problem, so all that JSP/JSTL code you've so far is irrelevant. All which counts is the (JSP-generated) HTML code and the browser itself.